# How can I add a WHERE statement to a WHERE statement in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'd like to do something like this:

`CASE
WHEN Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' THEN 'Gerp'
ELSE NULL
ENDS AS Herpty`
`WHERE Herpty IS NOT NULL`

The idea is that I'd like this to run in the same query, but problem is that it Postgres will usually tell me that Herpty doesn't exist (probably because it's being created in the same query)maybe there's a convention or work-around? The idea here for me would be to get a Herpty column excluding what's not `'Nerp'` in `Derp.Herp` and I don't want the NULLs back.

UPDATE: the answers I got so far did not help, my actual query is slightly more complicated, I can't put in the WHERE statement `WHERE Derp.Herp <> 'Nerp'` since in my actually Query it actually goes thru 2 columns in the WHEN statement, so it's more like this: 
`Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' AND  Derp.Burp = 'Durp' THEN 'Gerp'` so if I go to add that in the WHERE clause it gets ambiguous,  `WHERE Derp.Herp <> 'Nerp' AND  Derp.Burp <> 'Durp'` will eliminate Nerp and Durp completely even if they don't match in the 2 columns, I'm doing this work for a non-profit please help.

Here's my attempt at rewritting my code to reflect it more accurately: http://pastebin.com/PgvAFvfq

Comment: Can u write the complete query what u are working on...

Comment: Just performed an edit, answers are still welcome.

Comment: Can u write ur complete query...

Comment: I just added a pastebin with a better example of my code, I can't share the actual code, it's confidential information for a non-profit. But basically I'm trying to eliminate completely from the results what I'm not going to be putting in Edibles. I'm putting them as Nulls right now but it's returning me Nulls and I just want the results not being queried to completely go away.

Comment: Try the latest one I added just now..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, not exactly. It's a calculated column, it is not available in the WHERE clause. But according to your example, you could just do something like

```
WHERE Derp.Hepr <> 'NERP'
```

But then, your whole query seems pretty much useless. You should show us your real query.

Comment: Yes you're right, I feel so silly I did not think of Nerp within Derp.Herp

Comment: I just want to mention though that it's going to be a lot of work because ELSE NULL would turn anything that doesn't match my criteria into a NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can just reorganize your query a little;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' THEN 'Gerp' ELSE NULL ENDS AS Herpty 
WHERE Herpty IS NOT NULL
```

is the same as

```
SELECT 'Gerp' AS Herpty WHERE Derp.Herp = 'Nerp';
```

Comment: actually, that should be `Derp.Herp <> 'Nerp'`

Comment: @Adrian Um, are you sure? If `Derp.Herp = 'Nerp'` in the first version, it returns 'Gerp' and *all other* results are removed. Same with the second version.

Comment: OP wants records where Herpty is NOT null.

Comment: @Adrian Exactly, if Derp.Herp = 'Nerp', the result is a row with 'Gerp' in both versions. If Derp.Herp<>'Nerp', the result is no row in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

CASE WHEN Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' THEN 'Gerp' ELSE NULL ENDS AS Herpty WHERE CASE WHEN Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' THEN 'Gerp' ELSE NULL ENDS IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. I hope it will work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Derp.Herp = 'Nerp' AND Derp.Burp = 'Durp' 
            THEN 'Gerp'
FROM (SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE 
               WHERE Derp.Herp <> 'Nerp' AND Derp.Burp <> 'Durp') Derp
```

Comment: The problem though is that if I do that will it not Ignore all results that has Nerp in Derp.Herp and all the results that has Durp in Derp.Burp? in the examples I'm veryfing that if it's Derp.Herp = Nerp AND Derp.Burp = 'Durp' then it can make the changes to "Gerp" but in this example, I believe that if any result in Derp.Burp = 'Durp'  then it will cut it out, regardless if Derp.Herp is equal to 'Nerp' or something else.